# Turboair refrigerator short cycling

Tags: refrigerator

We moved our commercial turbo air refrigerator TGM22 and it stopped cooling.

I called repair, they came and charged the compressor but saw no leaks. It still doesn't cool. I had repair come back and they replaced the thermostat. It's still not cooling well, and I noticed it short cycles every 2 minutes. I called repair back several times and they don't return my calls.

I replaced the start relay and run capacitor. I cleaned out throughout and the compressor does get hot.

What do I do?  I can replace the start capacitor but there isn't much else to it. It didn't appear to have a contactor or computer board.

Any ideas welcome.

It does keep the fridge at about 46 degrees (cycling all the time).

Also, how hot should the tube from the condenser get? It seems to get hot and shut down while the chilled one gets cool but not cold?

Comment: Explain 'moved'.  Did you check level?

Comment: Did you transport it vertically, or lay it down to move it? Did you let it stand in its normal operationg position for 24 hours in the new location before turning it on?

Comment: I will take a swag and say either it has moisture in the freon system or the charge is not correct.  If I remember correctly it should maintain the temperature  from 33F to 38F for normal operation. I would suggest you get a different company and ask for your money back. Ask the new tec what the superheat temperature is and what it should be. Without knowing that it is extremely difficult to properly charge a system. Just a note on the side freon does not wear out and only needs more added to the system when some has leaked out.

Comment: Moved upright, tech said it had 1oz he added 6 for 7oz total.

Comment: Is it in an enclosed location where the hot air has no place to go?

Comment: Nope in basement open area.